# CakePHP 2.5. Create a hidden form element, error message: undefined offset

Tags: php, forms, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP 2.5 and i try to create a hidden form field, I am getting an error message:

> Notice (8): Undefined offset: 1
>   [ROOT\app\View\Helper\AppHtmlHelper.php, line 23]

I am trying: 
`Array( $this->Form->input( 'Model.field', Array( 'value' => 0, 'type' => 'hidden') ) )`

How can i create a hidden form field using CakePHP 2.5?

Comment: why are you putting your input inside an array?

Comment: just already was in that way , it is a legacy code that uses : echo `$this->Html->rows(
        array(
            array(
                array(` ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('Model.field', array('value' => '0'));
```

Docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::hidden

Comment: Perfect, it work´s thank you for the reference, best regards